# Prevent single quote on parameter in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins

I am facing a interesting problem in a Jenkins pipeline. I am trying to create a frontend ip for a load balancer in Azure with the following command:

```
sh "az network lb frontend-ip create \
    -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} \
    --lb-name ${LB_NAME} \
    --subnet '${SUBNET_ID}' \
    --name ${DNS_HOST} 
    --zone {1,2,3} \
    --only-show-errors"
```

The command works on my local computer, but in Jenkins `sh` puts single quotes around the `--zone` parameter and then the command fails (subnet was shortened to `****` by me for better visibility):

```
+ az network lb frontend-ip create -g RG --lb-name LB --subnet '****' --name NAME --zone '{1,2,3}' --only-show-errors
ERROR: az network lb frontend-ip create: '{1,2,3}' is not a valid value for '--zone'. Allowed values: 1, 2, 3.

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az network lb frontend-ip create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFrontendIp --lb-name MyLb --private-ip-address 10.10.10.100 --subnet MySubnet --vnet-name MyVnet
Create a frontend ip address for an internal load balancer.

az network lb frontend-ip create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFrontendIp --lb-name MyLb --public-ip-address MyFrontendIp
Create a frontend ip address for a public load balancer.

https://aka.ms/cli_ref
Read more about the command in reference docs
```

I tried a lot of combinations of escapes `\` and workarounds without success. Did anyone also faced this issue and was able to solve it?

Comment: the error message states that only one of 1, 2 or 3 is allowed, what are you trying to accomplish with `{1,2,3}`?

Comment: @criztovyl `{1, 2, 3}` is the right way to write the parameter. It works that way on my computer. Without the brackets the same error appears.

Comment: what does you shell say if you manually run it as `bash -xc 'az network lb ...'`? If you are using bash, it will expand to to "1 2 3", leading to `--zone 1 2 3`, with only `1` being passed to `--zone`. Jenkins might not use bash as a shell which in turn passes the `{1,2,3}` as-is.

Comment: `WorkflowScript: 101: expecting '}', found 'az network lb frontend-ip create -g ' @ line 101, column 30.
                       bash -xc "az network lb frontend-ip create -g RG --lb-name LB --subnet '****' --name NAME --zone {1,2,3} --only-show-errors"
`

Comment: what OS is your Jenkins running on?